# How to get Title Description and URL from Filckr for a set of photos

Tags: xml, silverlight, flickr

So I have a photo viewer that I am creating to learn Silverlight and I want to be able to  get all of the photos from flickr for a specific user/set.  I see that I can easily get the information in an atom feed but I can't easily get the description as the atom feed combines the Title/description etc and outputs it as html.  Is there any way to easily get the tite/description/url for a specific user/set in flickr?

Comment: What is the ATOM URL you are working from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ATOM, you could directly use the Flickr API. I've seen a number of people use the WebClient to interact with the Flickr API in Silverlight.

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Note that you will need to use an MD5 implementation for Silverlight if you have to "sign" your Flickr API calls.

Comment: Using the api is the only way to get the information that I want but it will take multiple calls which will be annoying.